# Passing Dynamic params in Active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-activestorage

I am using Active admin with active storage. 
Here the `User` model has `has_many_attached: files`. Here I have permit params like this `permit_params :name, :title, files: []`.

If I have multiple

```
has_many_attached: field_1_files, 
has_many_attached: field_2_files
......
has_many_attached: field_10_files.
```

Then How should permit params dynamically?

I have tried like this

```
permitted: [:name,:title]
(1..10).each do |i|
  permitted << "field_#{i}_files":[]
end
```

But This one raise an error. If there is any possible ways to implement this logic.

FYI: The Final output i.e permitted params should equivalent to

`permit_params [:name, :title, field_1_files: [], field_2_files: [], field31_files: [] ...field_10_files: []`

Thanks in Advance...